# Display custom attributes on form

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I am novice to CRM. I am trying to create a Form in CRM that would display all custom attributes for Custom Entity. How can I display it on the Form? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The 'easiest' way is to add these attributes by hand in the Forms Designer.